# How do you load a file into a variable in ant using the 'loadfile' task?

Tags: ant, ant-loadfile

I'm trying the following and it doesn't seem to work.

```
<property name="file.configs.txt" value="" />
...
<target name="...">
   <loadfile property="file.configs.txt" srcFile="remoteConfig/configs.txt" />
</target>
```

I read [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) that the <loadfile> task is supposed to load the contents of a file into the specified property.

Comment: For people who are looking for mutable variables in their ant build files I give you, the variable task: 
http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Properties are immutable in Ant.  The first definition of file.configs.txt will prevent it from being set again.

From: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html

Properties are immutable: whoever sets a property first freezes it for the rest of the build; they are most definitely not variables.

Comment: +1 Here's where this is documented: http://ant.apache.org/manual/CoreTasks/property.html

Comment: Yup that was it!  I defined the property before and I can't change the value.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Get rid of the property definition line.  [Properties are immutable](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).

```
 <project name="foobar" default="foo">
   <target name="foo">
     <loadfile property="foo.bar" srcFile="foobar/moo.txt"/>
     <echo>${foo.bar}</echo>
   </target>
 </project>
```